# Iterate over an unordered list in selenium and output price value

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I am scraping true car using selenium and python. I currently have the code set up to find the unordered list containing all listings and then iterate over them to print the price. Using the local xpath will only ever print the price value of the first element in the unordered list. I tried dynamically updating the xpath in the for loop such that the index in the xpath will change but then I get an error that it cannot find the element.
Here is the code I have to better demonstrate this.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get("https://www.truecar.com/used-cars-for-sale/listings/bmw/m4/location-palm-desert-ca/")


listingSection = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/main/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ul')
listings = listingSection.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "li")

for i, listing in enumerate(listings):
// wrong element
    price = listing.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id="mainContent"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div").text //this will only return the first item in the list and sadly the list elements do not have ids
// error
    price = listing.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//*[@id="mainContent"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[{i + 1}]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div").text // this returns an error
    print(price)
```

I know that the reason for this is likely that the id field for the xpath is not relative to the list elements themselves but since they have no ids I am not sure how to go about this as I am new to webscraping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't have `id`s but they do have `data-test` attribute, which I suspect was added for the purpose of Selenium testing.

```
listings = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-test="vehicleCardPricingBlockPrice"]')
for listing in listings:
    print(listing.text)
```

As a side not, when using `WebElement` to locate another `WebElement` with `xpath` you need to tell it to use current context with `.`

```
listing.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="mainContent"]')
```

Comment: Thank you! That returns to me price data. Could you help me understand how you found that ```data-test``` attribute. Also how would you recommend going about also screenshotting the listing associated to that element. Since the element we get here is only the one that contains price.

Comment: @TwoLeggedCat I didn't really do anything, just looked at the element in devtools. For the screenshots look for the element you do want, most of the items in the card have `data-test` attribute.

Comment: Thank you, your help has been much appreciated. What you told me about relative xpaths really helped me with my confusion and I'm starting to understand more how this works so thank you for taking the time.